# How to create csv table from Sharepoint List and save it on a blob

Tags: list, sharepoint, azure-blob-storage

I have a following question, could you please tell me how to create a table from the sharepoint list and save it on a blob storage

I followed this approach (img below) but I'm not sure if it is correct, I want if it is possible automatically to select all the columns not with the mapping

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I followed this approach (img below) but I'm not sure if it is correct

Yes, you need to map them by using select like below:

[image]

or by creating an array of json like below:

[image]

mapping it inside an array. Select action or initializing a json array or the input must be array of jsons,  is must when you are creating a csv file

And only after that you can create a CSV file and then create a blob in Azure blob storage.